# any common video format that will run on any browser?

Tags: html, flash

please any one can tell me video format that play on any browser , with play/pause/stop buttons? i have the following code for .swf but i cant get any button to control.

```
<object width="400" height="40"
classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/
pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0">
<param name="SRC" value="bookmark.swf">
<embed src="bookmark.swf" width="400" height="40"></embed>
</object>
```

Comment: as long as the person has flash installed, flash should work.

Comment: ok thankx ,but can i get get play/stops buttons on .swf video?

Comment: we can't answer that. it all depends on how its set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at something like [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/).

The current trend is to use HTML5 video to embed a player which is widely supported and does not require flash. This is particularly useful for devices such as the iPad/iPhone.
For browsers that do not support HTML, the pattern is to failover to a flash based version.

jPlayer handles a lot of this for you.

Comment: @user1122910 Yes, it has support back to IE6

Answer (score 0):

It will work if flash is instaled.

You can use Flash components to quickly setup a video player with controls

Comment: They are built-in on flash IDE (I am not sure about flex). Plz do your research!

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 video tag is supported in all major browsers.(in Internet Explorer: from version 9) You can give that a try.

Comment: that's not strictly true, you won't find support for it in previous versions of Internet Explorer